# Memory/Thread related Crash on Orientation change?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Friends,

onCreate() I am loading data from webservice using Async thread.
when thread is started it shows progress bar on screen and loads data.

A sudden problem I have faced is when I start that activity progress bar is shown I change orientation of my phone second thread starts &

Application crashes.(Inovation Target Exception something like that).

Here is the log cat any one guide me what is the solution to this problem?

Code is simple

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.searchbanks);
    threadBank = new AsyncBanks();
    threadBank.execute("","");
}




04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430): Activity com.FindMe.SearchBanks has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f64f98 that was originally added here
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.FindMe.SearchBanks has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f64f98 that was originally added here
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at com.FindMe.SearchBanks$AsyncBanks.onPreExecute(SearchBanks.java:133)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at com.FindMe.SearchBanks.LoadRecords(SearchBanks.java:115)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at com.FindMe.SearchBanks.onCreate(SearchBanks.java:76)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-29 16:08:26.811: ERROR/WindowManager(430):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:355)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:200)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeView(Window.java:432)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:278)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.app.Dialog.access$000(Dialog.java:71)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:111)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:268)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at com.FindMe.SearchBanks$AsyncBanks.onPostExecute(SearchBanks.java:197)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at com.FindMe.SearchBanks$AsyncBanks.onPostExecute(SearchBanks.java:1)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-29 16:08:28.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got answer myself.

[How to deal with orientation change with a ProgressDialog showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695484/how-to-deal-with-orientation-change-with-a-progressdialog-showing)

And

[How to handle Activity when Orientation changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438743/how-to-handle-activity-when-orientation-changes)

Comment: Wasn't that very close to the solution I suggested to you? You can see that I mentioned Config changes - orientation, but presumed that you were more familiar with the subject and did not want to go in more details.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you dismiss your dialog so that you can recreate it, there seems to be a race condition between the system destroying the dialog and the lifecycle methods where you would dismiss it.  Very rarely I get a crash report about dismissing a non-existent dialog at configuration change time.

I suggest catching and ignoring the exception in Dialog.dismiss() just to handle the race condition.  That's what I've done and it's cleared up my problem.

Steve @ WhitneyApps